# Resolve polygon parent relationship in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a layer in which, following geometry processing, the polygon of a zone that is a full enclave to another seems to have become its child object, which I think will cause problems down the line.  How can this be resolved so the enclave shares the same shapefile parent as its neighbour?

Thanks in advance.  [The Shapefile is available here.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/46043231/data/parent_problem_shapefile.zip)

The area:

[image]

The child feature (Carlisle) visible on inspection as child of surrounding Penrith.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried "**Join attributes by location**" and enabling the option _Keep all records_?

Comment: Hi Joseph. Doesn't seem to work for me sadly

Comment: You could create a rendering order which would always show the 'Carlisle' polygon above the others.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a layer that has a rendering order as mentioned in the comment above:

Create 2 rules using the rule-based style - one with no filters (meaning everything is shown) and another for Carlisle ("id" = 'Carlisle'). Change the rendering order and put the filter for Carlisle as the higher number.

Edit the layer and select all the polygons, I simply used *Select Features by Rectangle*. Create a new shapefile layer and *Copy*/*Paste* the polygons from the original layer to the new layer.

The new layer should now show the Carlisle polygon on top along with the neighbouring polygons.